# RestSharp no response when Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to use a very simple RestSharp client like this

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(@"http://hostname:28000");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("action", "getstatus");
var res = client.Execute(request);
```

However, this always fails with

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Block length does not match with its complement.
```

So the response does not contain any data.

What I noticed when I execute the request in a webrowser with a network tracer, it shows the Transfer-encoding as "chunked". This somehow seems to hinder RestSharp.
Running the same request with standard `HttpWebRequest` works fine.
Any ideas how to solve this with RestSharp?

//edit: The response should be a valid XML.

Comment: Are you sending a response as a compressed stream?

Comment: I am not doing anything else apart from what I posted above? Should I try this? If yes, how?
thanks!

Comment: I've read this: http://george.chiramattel.com/blog/2007/09/deflatestream-block-length-does-not-match.html 
which basically says that there is incompatibility between a `DeflateStream` and a `GZipStream`. but reading through the source code of `RestSharp` i see they are using a GZipStream if the header states so. Try adding `request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");`

Comment: Yeah I found this post as well and tried it. But with no success. Same as without setting the header

Comment: Do you control the response of the server? if you do, maybe try sending a raw `XML` instead of a compressed stream. Or, maybe try using `HttpClient` instead

Comment: No, I dont have any control over the behaviour of the server.

Comment: I have the same problem as well. Did you happen to solve it by now?

Comment: sorry, haven't looked into this in almost three years ;) So no, can't remember anymore if I solved it or just gave up